# Jenkins. How to configure tasks for specific git branch?

Tags: jenkins, configuration, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have multi-configuration project in Jenkins. My git repository have different branches. For example:

```
dev
stage
bug/code1
feature/code2
etc...
```

I want to create different `Post build tasks`, `Publish HTML reports` etc for each branch.

What is the problem? I changed configuration for `stage` branch. All works fine only before `Branch Indexing`. After this process, custom configuration for each branch replaced by `multi-configuration project`. It means if I added specific task only for `stage` branch, after `Branch Indexing` task will be removed.

[Multi-Branch Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin) says this:

> Sub-projects appear to be configurable, but they will be overwritten
>   by branch indexing if you manually modify them.  There is no clear way
>   to remove or hide the configuration option on sub-projects (except
>   maybe with project-based matrix authorization??), though version 0.1.x
>   of this plugin accomplished that via some trickery that is not
>   possible in newer versions.

**So my question is:** How I can create custom configuration for each branch? Or what is the best solution for this? Maybe I should create different projects for `stage`, `dev` branches?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the similar situation like you, more than 10 branches need to be maintained. Instead of using multi branch plugin, we use job dsl to create the jobs for each branch.

For example, hello_branch1, hello_branch2....

Inside our job dsl project, we save the different json config for the different branches. In your case, you can think we save the post build script, or report to be published....

This will make sure the generated jobs are standalone and will not affect each other.

Br,

Tim

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll wait a couple of days. If this is the best solution then I will give you more points ;)

Comment: So you best of the best ). I propose one more solution. Create 2 multi-projects and configure patterns(or regexp) for exclude/include branches. For example, `dev` project uses next include branches: `dev feature/**`. For second project - another branches. Anyway thanks for help.